# Python is stalling on the first line of my for loop

Tags: python-3.x, group-by

I am trying to iterate through df.groupby groups, but python is stalling at the line where I define my for loop.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
def plot_data(data, root_path):
    groups = data.groupby(['path','iteration'])
    print('groups created')

    for plot_id, ((path, iteration), df) in enumerate(groups, 1):
        print('Plotting path {} iteration {}'.format(path, iteration))
        
        fig, axs= plt.subplots(4,1, figsize=(15,10))
        axs[0].plot(df['rr'], df['true_P1z'], color='b', linestyle='--', label='model Pz')
```

The output prints 'groups created', but after running it for 10 mins, it still hasn't printed the 'Plotting path...' line. I assume it's getting stuck on the line between these print statements. I'm not sure how to begin debugging this, since my code is just stalling and isn't throwing any errors. Thanks!